# Flutter http request not accepting headers but it works on postman

Tags: json, flutter, http

I am getting a really frustrating experience. Am making a post request to an api, works well on postman but refuses to work on flutter.

[image: Postman Image]

Here is the error response which tells me this is an issue with the headers.

```
 {"message":"Missing/Incorrect Security Key Header","apiVersion":"v1","transactionRef":"N202204281825312267","data":null,"error":{"code":401,"message":"Authorization failed for this request!"}}
```

**My Request**

```
 static Future<dynamic> postRequest(String url) async {
    http.Response response = await http.post(Uri.parse(url),
      headers: <String, String>{
        "Access-Key" : "6a637874-0394-4d9d-a803-86323c1ddc4d",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type" : 'application/json',
      },
    );
    print(response.body);
    print(url);
    try {
      if (response.statusCode == 200) {
        String data = response.body;
        var decodedData = jsonDecode(data);
        return decodedData;
      } else {
        return response.body;
      }
    } catch (e) {
      return response.body;
    }
  }
```

Comment: One thing to know is that Dart `http` will lower-case the header name. Try your postman request again but with `access-key` instead. If that fails, your server/API isn't accepting lower case headers (which it should).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would like to introduce you to another package in Flutter which makes working with http requests much easier, it's called Dio. Everything works the same, it also removes some boilerplate by default, you don't have to parse url, you can directly pass the url string. You don't have to encode/decode json. Instead of
passing headers attribute in http, dio works the following way,

Add the dependency to pubspec.yaml file and import dio.dart file.

Instructions can be found here https://pub.dev/packages/dio

Here's an example:

```
Future fetchData () async {
  Dio dio = new Dio();
  String url = 'example.com';
  
  final response = await dio.post(
  url,
  options: Options(
    headers: {'Access-Key': 'key'},
  );
  print(response.data);
}
```

Comment: seems like this package lowercase the header keys too

Comment: I use Rest APIs connected with MongoDB and there's an 'Authorization' header with the 'A' capital. It works perfectly fine for me. Maybe your issue is something else. Are you getting the same error?